# inject object without access to injector in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dependencies, guice

I am working on an existing Java code base that uses Guice for Dependency Injection. I have a new class Foo that has one member field (bar) I wanted to inject in. Like this:

```
public class Foo {
    @Inject
    private Bar bar;
}
```

However, there are two things:

1. There is no direct access to the injector where the Foo is used.
2. The client wants to use "new" to create Foo.

Is it still possible to inject Bar into Foo object when the clients do:

```
myFoo = new Foo();
```

I am very new to DI and Guice,  don't really understand how you can inject objects without calling injector.createInstance() on its class or its container class. It seems not working in my testing.

Answer (score 3):

No DI tool works if you create your instances via "new" yourself. That's not guice specific. So unless you drop your constraint "2", you will have a hard time.

Comment: i think you are right, after doing more research now I understand it a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

With Guice you can [force the injection of fields](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#on-demand-injection) if you have a reference to the injector. Like this:

```
injector.injectMembers(fooObject);
```

Your first point says you don't have access to the injector where Foo is used. Well, you can try to solve that giving Foo a static reference to the injector.

```
public class Foo {
  @Inject private static Injector injector;

  @Inject
  private Bar bar;

  public Foo() {
    injector.injectMembers(this);
  }
}
```

But wait, that won't work out of the box because the `injector` field would just be null. You need to inject it also but, as it is a static field, you just do it once. It is called [static injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#static-injections). Probably at application start where you have access to the Guice injector, in any of the guice modules.

There, you just execute this:

```
requestStaticInjection(Foo.class)
```

Comment: this looks pretty magic. I will note this down. On the other hand, it does not feel elegant for this case IMO. Now I've tried to inject the Bar in the place where "new Foo" is called and just pass Bar as parameter into Foo. It seems to be working.